# Neo4j: Monitoring and logging Indexing as it happens

Tags: neo4j

I have a Neo4j database with roughly 417 million nodes, 780 million relationships and 2.6 billion properties.
As creating indexes takes considerable amount of time, is there any way in Neo4j to trace and monitor the progress of index creation?

Answer (score 1):

In the Neo4j browser, use the command

```
:SCHEMA
```

to get information about the indexes, including if they are online or still being built.

Use

```
:SCHEMA await
```

to wait for indexes to be built.